# Isomorphic free groups have bijective generating sets

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

Let $F(X)$ be the free group on a set $X$. Classically, we can prove the statement:

> $F(X) \cong F(Y)$ if and only if $|X|=|Y|$.

The proofs (that I have seen) consist of turning the group isomorphism into an isomorphism of free abelian groups, then an isomorphism of vector spaces by modding out by some $p$. Where we can deduce that isomorphic vector spaces have bijective basis sets.

The last part of this proof uses AC. I came across [Kleppmann - Generating sets of free groups and the axiom of choice](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.201300088), which proves that ZF + boolean prime ideal theorem can prove this, therefore it is weaker than AC.

I am interested in knowing how true this statement is constructively. I.e. are uses of excluded middle and choice (or rather statements weaker than choice) necessary to prove it?

Comment: The statement is way too vague and has several interpretations. I guess you mean the statement "if there is an isomorphism from the free group on $X$ and the free group on $Y$, then there is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$".

Comment: @YCor What else could it mean?

Comment: @MikeShulman when I first read it, I thought of it as "there exists a free generating subset of the first one and...etc." I converged to the wording I'm writing just by elimination. Actually  "free" is hopelessly ambiguous since mathematicians use the same word for "free over some given subset" and "free over some subset"; of course often this doesn't matter, but precisely here it matters.

Comment: In Kleppmans dissertation (which includes results from that paper you cite) it is asked if any choice is need. I guess there is a similar question you can ask for vector spaces and that is not a theorem of ZF (found in  L ̈auchli.   Auswahlaxiom in der Algebra): that is there is a vector space, in a suitable model, with two bases of different cardinalities.

Comment: @YCor Hopefully things are more clear now.

Comment: @PaulPlummer's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359195/isomorphic-free-groups-have-bijective-generating-sets#comment904060_359195): [Läuchli - Auswahlaxiom in der Algebra](http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/BF02566957) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=143705)).  I *think* the Kleppman reference is actually to [Kleppmann - Generating sets of free groups and the axiom of choice](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/malq.201300088) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3207213)) (two 'n's).

Comment: @LSpice This is [Kleppmann's dissertation](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/253759) which I think Paul was referring to.

Comment: I’d expect that most constructive uses focus on the countable case, where countable choice or dependent choice might be enough.

Comment: Your last parenthesis ("more rather statements weaker than choice") doesn't make sense to me.  Is it what was intended?

Comment: @LSpice Maybe that wasn't the best way to phrase it. BPIT is strictly weaker than AC so the proof I am looking for would use ZF + something weaker than choice.

Comment: It's not a big deal, but I just can't parse it, even understanding what you mean.  Is 'more' meant to be 'or'?

Comment: @LSpice I've changed it to "or" as that sounds better.

Comment: Is the case of vector spaces already known? For instance, let $F^2_X$ be the free 2-elementary abelian group on $X$. Is ZF(+DC?) + "there's an isomorphism $F^2_{\mathbf{R}}\to F^2_{\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Q}}$" + "there is no bijection $\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Q}$" consistent (assuming ZF consistent)? (I allow middle choice here, at least to understand my own question)

Comment: @YCor: I feel like I asked this before, what's a 2-elementary abelian group? (Too elementary?)

Comment: @AsafKaragila a $p$-elementary abelian group, for prime $p$, is a synonym of vector space over the field on $p$ elements (I don't think a terminology question can be too elementary!). Purely group-wise, it means abelian group in which $px=0$ for all $p$.

Comment: @YCor: So free 2-elementary abelian = the finite subsets of $X$ (with symmetric difference as addition)? (Also, I had meant that maybe the groups are too elementary... :-P)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, this is one realization of 'the' free 2-elementary abelian group over $X$.

Comment: @YCor: Well, in that case, you can easily see that the cardinality of $F^2_{\Bbb R}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$, while that of $F^2_{\Bbb{R/Q}}$ is at least $|\Bbb{R/Q}|$ (and probably equal, but it's too early in the morning for this. So if there is no bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb{R/Q}$, the groups will not be isomorphic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks, indeed. Does there always exist (say in ZF+DC) a bijection $X\to F_X^2$ for every infinite $X$? (oh,probably not)

Comment: @YCor: Of course not. Since that would imply every infinite set has the same cardinality as its finite subsets, which implies $X\times X$ is equipotent with $X$, which implies choice.

Comment: OK thanks, so I should restate my question replacing $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Q}$ with $X$ and $X^2$ for $X$ such that there is no injection $X^2\to X$. Namely: is it consistent (for some such $X$, and say with ZF+DC) that there is an group isomorphism $F^2_X\to F^2_{X^2}$ (or $F_X\to F_{X^2}$)?

Comment: @YCor: Good question. I feel like the answer should be yes. But I have nothing off hand to give you as an example.